# CSS Validator at media syntax

Tags: css, w3c-validation

Hi I did the css validator and I got these:

> only 0 can be a length. You must put a unit after your number ){ *{ background:white url("../images/background1024768.png") no-repeat left top} }

what's up with that may be is because of the @media property? Am I doing it wrong? here's the css:

```
@media(min-width:1280){
*{    background:white url("../images/background1280800.png") no-repeat left top;} 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a unit. `min-width:1280px`

Also per style guides, avoid using quotes in background URLs.

`background:white url(../images/background1280800.png) top left no-repeat`

Comment: I agree that quotes are unnecessary, but which standards say to leave them out?

Comment: Not technically standards I suppose, guidelines or style guides. But Google's HTML and CSS style guide suggests to omit the quotes. See: http://goo.gl/4XLYF

Comment: they suggest omitting quotes for a cheap way to make their code smaller. quotes are standards and exist for a reason.